# Jetpack Compose: Adding a character counter to BasicTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to add a character counter inside a BasicTextField (I cant use TextField. It has to be below the Material level). I added a BasicText in the decorator but now I need to update it whenever someone changes the text. How do I get the text string from the innerTextField and update my BasicText?

```
@Composable
fun MyTextField(
    value: TextFieldValue,
    onValueChange: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    val charCount = 0 // How do I update this in onValueChange?

    BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        modifier = modifier,
        decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
            ) {
                BasicText(text = charCount.toString())
                Spacer(Modifier.width(5.dp))
                innerTextField()
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Off the cuff, have `charCount` be a `mutableStateOf { 0 }` that you `remember`. Then, have the `onValueChange` parameter to `BasicTextField` both call your `onValueChange` function parameter and update `charCount` based on the current text length.

Comment: you don't need a counter at all, you always have it `value.text.count()`, and it'll only be recomposed when text updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `val charCount = value.text.count()`. It will always be up to date thanks to recomposition happening automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `onValueChange = onValueChange,` with:

```
onValueChange = {
   charCount = it.text.length()
   onValueChange(it)
},
```